# How to find end point of arc with start point and center of arc in java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I want to find end point of a arc using start point and center point. then i want to draw a new arc using the end point (as center of new arc). but i don't know how i find end point.

p2 is center of old arc.

thanks.

```
int x = p2.x-radius;
int y = p2.y-radius;
int width = 2*radius;
int height = 2*radius;
int startAngle=(int)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(p1.y-p2.y, p1.x-p2.x));
startAngle=(startAngle>0)?(360-startAngle):(startAngle*(-1));

int endAngle=(int)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(p3.y-p2.y, p3.x-p2.x));
endAngle=endAngle>0?360-endAngle:endAngle*(-1);
int sweepAngle=Math.abs(startAngle-endAngle);
g.drawArc(x, y, width, height,startAngle,sweepAngle);
```

so, How do i draw new arc?

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow, can you please clarify some aspects of your question? For example, what `p1` represents?, What are you trying to achieve with the posted code? Geometrical problems are better described with drawings, can you provide a sketch to complement the textual description? If so, please highlight the unknown variable

Comment: Thanks. I want to draw a bisector. As you know, three arc is needed. i get three point from user(p1, p2 (as apex) and p3) by clicking. i drew first arc(the center is p2), then i drew second arc (center is the intersection of the first arc and line1(p1-p2)). now, i need end point of second arc (the intersection of the second arc and line2(p2-p3)) as center of third arc for drawing it. the line connect the intersection point of second arc and third arc and p2 is the bisector.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand your requirement, you want to draw a [bisector](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/bisector.html), but based on what I understand by bisector, you don't need three [arcs](http://www.mathopenref.com/arc.html), only three points or a point and an angle. You mention 3 arcs, but a bisector will split an arc in 2... Being honest, the provided geometric description is hard to follow without a proper sketch, provide one and I will upvote your question